# Preview Does Not Match with the Emulator

Tags: android-layout

I don't know why my Android layout does not match with the emulator. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Here is the layout code for the action sheet. The section that isn't displaying right is in the last linear layout

This is my activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logotitipdonk"
        android:transitionName="logo_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
        android:text="Hello there, Welcome Back"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:transitionName="logo_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slogan_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In to continue"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/username"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:text="Forget Password?" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#000"
            android:text="GO"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:text="New User? SIGN UP"
            android:textColor="#000" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

This is my build gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.titipdonk"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
}
```

My Android emulator preview:
[image: My android emulator preview]

Edit: In addition to a fix for this specific problem does anyone know why the preview doesn't match the way it actually shows up on the phone?

Comment: Hi LoackerHD, and welcoma at Stack Overflow :-) - can you please edit your question, the image is not displayed because it is inside the code block.

Answer (score 0):

Following are my suggestions for your code:

1. Your layout size in android studio preview should match to screen size of AVD.
2. Do not use absolute height and width for each component such as,

   ```
   android:layout_width="30dp"

   android:layout_height="40dp"
   ```

Instead use,

```
android:layout_width="match_parent/fill_parent/wrap_content"

android:layout_height="match_parent/fill_parent/wrap_content"
```

3. When you use absolute height and width such as 300dp or 400dp, components will be shown differently on each screen size and they may go outside of screen also
4. You can also use padding,margin and gravity for component position.

In your code use the `layout_width="match_parent"` and then use `gravity="center/left/right"`